# Exception when rendering card created by designer

Tags: c#, adaptive-cards

Can somebody please help me, what is wrong with this card?
It works in https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ but I get this exception when trying in my bot in emulator:

> Exception thrown: 'Jurassic.JavaScriptException' in Jurassic.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'Jurassic.JavaScriptException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter:Error: Exception caught : Error: Invalid value type: undefined

The exception occurs when I try to transform the template and the data:

```
var cardJson = transformer.Transform(cardtemplate, carddata);
```

The `carddata` is an empty json in my test. In production, I can receive different responses (like: hit, miss or gameover), where some of the data is missing.

**Update**: I think, I narrowed it down, the problem seems that the engine doesn't like if a referenced data is missing in the $when property like:
`"$when": "{result.shipStatus== 'HIT'}"`. Is there any workaround for this issue, that can be solved inside the card, or with very small change in the code? Like a propert to handle missing data as false?

card json:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "id": "playing",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Shots: {result.score.nrMoves}"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Hits: {result.score.nrHits}"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Missed: {result.score.nrMisses}"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "{result.shipStatus}",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                    "height": "stretch",
                                    "color": "{if(result.shipStatus == 'HIT', 'good', 'attention')}",
                                    "size": "ExtraLarge"
                                }
                            ],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                        }
                    ],
                    "separator": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "$when": "{result.shipStatus== 'HIT'}",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "{result.hitShip.name}",
                            "size": "Large",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "color": "Accent",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Target:",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                                    "height": "stretch",
                                    "weight": "Bolder",
                                    "size": "Medium"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                    "placeholder": "A1",
                                    "value": "",
                                    "id": "id_x"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "id": "",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.Submit",
                            "title": "Shoot",
                            "id": "",
                            "style": "positive",
                            "data": {
                                "action": "shoot"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "$when": "{result.gameProgress == 'PLAYING'}"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Game Over!",
                    "color": "Accent",
                    "size": "ExtraLarge",
                    "fontType": "Monospace",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                }
            ],
            "id": "gameover",
            "$when": "{result.gameProgress == 'GAMEOVER'}"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "value": "{result.gameUid}",
            "size": "Small",
            "wrap": true,
            "id": "GameID",
            "isVisible": false
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

Comment: Does the exception have a message?

Comment: Added one more line, not sure if it is relevant. This is all I have.

Comment: @vilmarci - You haven't said when the exception occurs, but I'm guessing it's when the bot tries to send the card rather than when the user clicks on the card. Are we to assume that the exception occurs when you try to expand the template? You can run your bot in debug mode since you're running it locally, and then you'll be able to see the exact line that's throwing the exception. In any case, you'll need to provide a lot more details like your code and your repro steps. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Updated my question with the exact line where the exception occurs.

Comment: @vilmarci - Can you provide some sample data for us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @vilmarci - Are you still working on this?

Comment: This task has now lower priority, as the even I made the game interface is over, but I didn't add any data to the card. I tested with empty json.